# Relationism, Substantivalism, and Simultaneity?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, ontology, physics, interpretation

I've been breaking my head open lately over special relativity and its conception of spacetime's dynamical as well as kinematical features. One thing that has stuck in my head is that of whether the concept of relative/absolute simultaneity in a relationist spacetime is different from a substantivalist spacetime? What I mean by relationism and substantivalism is the anti-realist vs. realist distinction between whether spacetime is, generally as i've understood it, reducible or irreducible (has to be taken as a real primitive thing).

Given the assumption that we know spacetime is a real thing, then the concept of relative simultaneity in special relativity or absolute simultaneity in [Lorentzian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_ether_theory) relativity takes on a similar philosophical flavor to presentations of the theory i've seen in other places. What if, however, we treat relativistic spacetime in a relationist guise? Do the concepts of absolute/relative simultaneity change and how? Further, in what ways do these two presentations of simultaneity in different ontological frameworks differ or remain the same?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106402/discussion-on-question-by-justin-orosz-relationism-substantivalism-and-simulta).

Answer (score 0):

> I've been breaking my head open lately over special relativity and its conception of spacetime's dynamical as well as kinematical features.

Given that you've also written

> then the concept of relative simultaneity in special relativity or absolute simultaneity in Lorentzian relativity takes on a similar philosophical flavor to presentations of the theory i've seen in other places.

Perhaps you need to clarify for yourself as to your understanding of the physics here at stake. It's absolute simultaneity in Newtonian spacetime, and relative simultaniety in Lorentzian spacetime, which is merely special relativity generalised to other spatial dimensions.

Comment: Not necessarily, as is presented here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_ether_theory. I'm not talking about lorentzian spacetime in that paragraph i'm talking about a rival interpretation of special relativity that goes by lorentzian relativity. Loot it up i'm not abusing the terminology its already been misused. Lorentzian relativity merely adds an extra preferred frame of reference in a still definitely existant spacetime.

Comment: I know its confusing that Minkowski spacetime is sometimes called Lorentzian spacetime and there is a rival interpretation of special relativity that goes by Lorentz-ether theory or sometimes just Lorentzian special relativity.

Comment: @JustinOrosz: Whats confusing is the way you have phrased your question. Given that you know that there is such a thing as Lorentzian spacetime, I find it odd that you might not think that when referring to Lorentzian relativity people might not suppose ordinary special relativity generalised to Lorentizian spacetimes.

Comment: I assumed most people knew about Lorentz vs Einstein relativistic interpretations. Further when others refer directly to the actual spacetime structure of special relativity they usually preface it by saying its Minkowski spacetime.

Comment: @Thevictorioustruther: And besides, the Wikipedia article you linked to calls it "The Lorentz Ether Theory", presumably to avoid confusion with relativity per se.

Answer (score 0):

As I learn from the comments to your question you compare two rival theories to explain the Michelson-Morley experiment (MM), which does not show any movement against a hypothetical ether:

•   **Lorentz Ether Theory** (LET) due to Lorentz. (In your question „relationist(?)=substantivalist(?)“) LET explains the negative answer of the MM-experiment by the Lorentz contraction with the factor gamma=1/sqrt(1-(v/c)**2.

•   **Special Relativity** (SR) due to Einstein. (In your question „relativist(?)“). SR dismisses the whole ether concept as obsolete. SR is based on the Lorentz transformation, which represents the symmetry group of Maxwell’s electrodynamics, and on the hypothesis of the observer independent constant speed of light.

History has shown that the more radical SR introduces more powerful concepts than LET, hence SR has more explanatory value. The basic ideas of the two approaches are completely different. Hence I cannot recognize the benefit when treating „relativistic spacetime in a relationist guise“.

Don’t you think it could be like filling new wine into old skins?

Answer (score 0):

I personally have always liked the idea that space and time don't have a separate existence but are just ideas to help use make sense of the fact that things and events have gaps between them. However, the more I have learned about General Relativity the harder it is for me to think of spacetime in a relationist way. It seems hard, to me at least, to make sense of curved spacetime if spacetime doesn't exist- since you would effectively have to find an alternative reason to explain why objects and events behaved and occurred *as if* spacetime was curved, because surely they do.

And that personal diversion brings me to your question. Let's ignore the complexities of General Relativity and content ourselves with flat spacetime. Either you can take the conventional view that spacetime exists, and all objects trace out trajectories in it (world-lines) or you can take the view that spacetime does not exist as a standalone physical entity- space is just a way of conceiving the gaps between things, and time is just a counter of sorts we use to quantify relations between types of changes. In either case, you must take into account of the fact that the speed of light is the same in every inertial frame.

If we adopt the relationist view, time is simply a counter of change, with clocks being the exemplars of periodic change that we use as yardsticks for comparison. What can simultaneity possibly mean in a relationist view? Normally we think of simultaneity as meaning that the time in one place is the same as the time in another. But if we claim that time does not exist, how can you adopt that definition of simultaneity? The classic way to solve the problem is to exploit the constancy of the speed of light. If you have two clocks some distance apart, you can say that the clocks are meaningfully synchronised if they give the right duration for the passage of light from one clock to the other. Very good. I can now have a long chain of clocks ahead or behind me which I know are in synch in a meaningful way because they record the right times for the passage of light between any two points on the chain. I can now have a relationist meaning of 'simultaneous' which is that two events are simultaneous if they occur when the same 'time' number is displayed on nearby clocks. The issue then, is that if you are moving relative to me, and you have your own set of clocks which are synchronised according to the same principle I used to synchronise mine- ie they all give the correct time for the passage of light between any two points on the chain- we will find that the times shown along your chain of clocks is out of synch with the times shown on mine. In either the relationist or substantivist view, simultaneity, as I have defined it, must be relative.